# Iteratively Accessing and Setting Model Fields

Tags: django, django-models

I'm trying to iteratively set the individual fields in my model from a POST call without writing a bunch of individual set and get methods. Unfortunately, the only methodology I've conceptualized looks extremely hacky and I can't even make it work. I feel like I'm doing something the hard way or fighting against the design of the language and was hoping someone could point me in the right direction:

#### My Modify Function

```py
def modify(request, specification_id):
    spec = get_object_or_404(Specification, pk=specification_id)
    user = request.user
    try:
        for key, value in request.POST.iteritems():
            if spec._get_FIELD_display(spec._meta.get_field_by_name(key)[0]) != value:
                #This would be where the setter would go if I could figure out how to make it work
```

```py
class Specification(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField(max_length=40000)
    last_modified = models.DateTimeField('Date Last Modified')
```

Comment: Where is the question? This might be better posted to http://www.djangosnippets.org or some similar site.